# VB.NET - Edit file property "Company" etc?

Tags: vb.net, file, file-io, io

I was wondering how I can set a file's properties? I'm talking about the fields, author, company etc. I found a way of doing it through Word's builtin properties. But it's a little buggy. So I was wondering if it's possible to do that in other ways?

I have this code that works for all Word document files except *.doc format it seems.
This is the code I have so far, one text box and one button. The button runs findDocLoop()

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oBuiltInProps As Object

  Public Sub findDocLoop()
        Dim strRootPath As String
        strRootPath = txtBoxRootpath.Text

        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(strRootPath)
        Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.doc")
        Dim aryFi2 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.dot")
        Dim aryFi3 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.doc*")

        Dim fi As IO.FileInfo


        For Each fi In aryFi
            If Not fi.FullName.Contains("~$") Then
                RunRenameProcess(txtBoxRootpath.Text & "\" & fi.ToString)
            End If
        Next

        For Each fi In aryFi2
            If Not fi.FullName.Contains("~$") Then
                RunRenameProcess(txtBoxRootpath.Text & "\" & fi.ToString)
            End If
        Next

        For Each fi In aryFi3
            If Not fi.FullName.Contains("~$") Then
                RunRenameProcess(txtBoxRootpath.Text & "\" & fi.ToString)
            End If
        Next

        oDoc = Nothing

        lblDone.Text = "Finished"

    End Sub

    Public Function FileInUse(ByVal sFile As String) As Boolean
        Dim thisFileInUse As Boolean = False
        If System.IO.File.Exists(sFile) Then
            Try
                Using f As New IO.FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
                    thisFileInUse = False
                End Using
            Catch
                thisFileInUse = True
                writeToLog(sFile)
            End Try
        End If
        Return thisFileInUse
    End Function

    Public Sub writeToLog(ByVal strFile As String)
        Dim sContents As String
        sContents = strFile & " - " & DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString
        SaveTextToFile(sContents, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\errorlog.txt")
    End Sub

    Private Sub RunRenameProcess(ByVal strFile)

        If FileInUse(strFile) = False Then
            'Create instance of Word and make it visible
            'On Error Resume Next
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(strFile)

            'Get the properties collection in file
            oBuiltInProps = oDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties

            'Set the value of the properties
            oBuiltInProps.Item("Company").Value = txtBoxCompany.Text
            ' AT THIS POINT, THE PROPERTY IS ACTUALLY SET (IF I CHECK IN WORD)

            oDoc.Save()
            ' AT THIS POINT, THE PROPERTY IS RESET TO THE DEFAULT WORD COMPANY VALUE(DOMAIN)
            oDoc.Close()
        End If

    End Sub
```

I know it can probably be done better, but I'm kinda in a hurry. I just noticed when I set a break point right after the code sets the value of the property. I set Word to be open, got in there and checked the property value. And it was actually set!. But after the save phaze, it seems to be lost. Or "reset" to some Office defaults. Which is my company name.

Comment: Basically all Word files. I tried opening a winword.exe and doing it through there, but for some reason, files with "doc" extention doesn't get their properties saved. It's weird. It works on docx, docm" etc, in the same loop.

Comment: You have to use Word interop to do this.  You leave no clue why "it is a little buggy".

Comment: Well, by a little buggy, I mean that I have this loop for each of *.doc files and for each file, run this function. In this function, I open the Word document and edit the document properties. I have author, company etc in there. And for all of the files except .doc files, it's working. The property is saved when I save the document. Only not for .doc files. Which I find strange. I can update my previous code in the first post

Comment: I've found it's actually the Save process that resets the document property of the doc files. I tried to pause the code right after it had set the property (I was the property was set), and chose to manually save the document. And the property was reset then as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this does what you need? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163637.aspx

Comment: It's really weird. Even using this code the same thing happens. I can see that I do set the Company property during the code. But as soon as I save the document and close it, the property is filled back in. And it only happens for .doc files! This is really weird.

Comment: Is it just removing this information? There's a method for this I think?

Comment: Well, it seems as though the information is reset. It's very strange, it just resets it to whatever Company information is added to the Word installation. For my case, this is probably OK for now, since it's the company name that's supposed to go there anyway, but I have no control of it at later dates.